# Running Spring Boot cmd-line sample gives `Could not find method run()`

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a simple command-line utility with Spring Boot.

I started with the Spring Boot sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple).

Running `gradle build` gives:

> Could not find method run() for arguments [build_54mbijt3lmz0e8z5tqchytm9o$_run_closure2@65b43076] on root project 'spring-boot-sample-simple'.

What is missing from the [gradle build file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple/build.gradle) to make it run correctly?

Comment: Please share the relevant part of the build script.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, like a misspelling in build.gradle file or it was not properly updated since plugin version changed. It has a `run` task (which was available in first versions of the plugin), which doesn't exist yet, but `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` applied to this example provides a `bootRun` task insteadof it. You can read about it [in the official reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications).

You can just rename a:

```
run {
  systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

to

```
bootRun {
  systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

And use `gradle bootRun` to build and run this application, or just `gradle build` to build it.

Answer (score 2):

if you open the projects build.gradle file and comment out these lines like so:

```
/*
run {
  systemProperties = System.properties
}
*/
```

it will build ok.